# How do you update counter_cache in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many

I have a normal association in my Rails app:

- `CustomerAccount has_many :orders`
- `Order belongs_to :customer_account`

Now, I've added a `:counter_cache => true` to the `belongs_to` statement and added the `orders_count` column to `CustomerAccount`

After the migration, every value in the `orders_count` column is 0. How do I update all these values to have the correct count?

Answer (score 2):

```
CustomerAccount.find_each do |customer_account|
  CustomerAccount.reset_counters(customer_account.id, :orders)
end
```

Comment: This is better than mine, i didn't know about the `reset_counters` method.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, that's why we're here.  Glad to return the favour, I've learnt a lot off your answers on here.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in your migration file:

```
class AddTasksCount < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def self.up  
    add_column :projects, :tasks_count, :integer, :default => 0  

    Project.reset_column_information  
    Project.all.each do |p|  
      p.update_attribute :tasks_count, p.tasks.length  
    end  
  end  

  def self.down  
    remove_column :projects, :tasks_count  
  end  
end
```

Comment: The model is CustomerAccount, not Project.

Answer (score 0):

Do another migration which has the following in its up block:

```
CustomerAccount.all.each do |account| 
  account.update_attributes(:orders_count => account.orders.size)
end
```